# How to use Blazeds with a custom classloader?

Tags: java, apache-flex, blazeds, classloader

has anybody tried using a custom classloader with BlazeDS?

We have a web application using BlazeDS and we can convert Java objects in to ActionScript object and back without problems in the main application. However, we also have a plug-in mechanism based on a custom classloader. BlazeDS cannot map the types contained in jar files of that custom classloader since I don't know how to tell it to BlazeDS. Has anybody already done this?

The livedocs of [TypeMarshallingcontext](http://livedocs.adobe.com/blazeds/1/javadoc/flex/messaging/io/TypeMarshallingContext.html) show a setClassloader() method, but since the context seems to be a singleton, I assume this will not work if you have multiple custom classloaders (we have 1 for each plugin that is deployed)

regards,

Wim

Comment: Are you invoking remote methods from the classes loaded through the plug-in mechanism?

Comment: Yes, we got that working but all parameters and the return type have to be from 'built-in' types, they cannot be from a type that is only known in the plugin.

Comment: Note that the context is not a singleton like I mention in my question , but a ThreadLocal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never did that, but I think you can build a custom Classloader which will delegate the findclass method to the children cloassloaders (and check if they are to find it or not), and set this classloader in the TypeMarshallingContext.

Comment: See http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?p=298599 for it goes so far. I got a proof of concept working, but not there fully yet.

Comment: Just to confirm that I got it fully working now. Thanks for the help!